# Apache Superset - "or"-combining filters

Tags: filter, apache-superset

There is a node graph that I would like to be able to filter based on particular nodes, not directed links, which is the data structure it asks for. Which is to say, I would like to see all links inbound to *or* outbound out of a node.

Filtering on "from" and "to" columns is easy, but the filters overlap with an "and" pattern - meaning, if I filter for the same node in "to" and "from" filters, I get an empty graph (or I would get a graph with the sole node and all links that loop on that node, but I have no loops in mine).

Being able to combine filters with an "or" - or, better yet, group filters together to then decide whether to "and" or "or" them together within the group or with other groups - would be awfully nice, but it does not appear to be possible in stock Superset (it would also be relatively simple and very useful to incorporate as part of query building - encase each group in parens, use "and"/"or" between those. Maybe you could nest those groups, too).

Is there any workaround that would permit to use "or" with Superset filters? Failing that, what should I look for to add that functionality myself?